# Как инициализировать двухмерный массив typescript?

Tags: typescript

Как инициализирвоать массив Get? Я как уже не пытался все никак:

```
import Cell from './Cell';

export default class Cells {  
    Get: Cell[];

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {

        for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            this.Get[i] = new Cell[x];
            for (let j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                this.Get[i][j] = new Cell(x, y, this._createHtmlElement());
            }
        }

    }

    _createHtmlElement(): HTMLElement {
        let t = document.createElement("div");
        t.classList.add("cell");
        return t;
    }
}
```

В данной реализации ошибка такая:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__Cell__.a[x] is not a constructor
```

Видимо у класса Cell должен быть конструктор без параметров. Я бы конечно его сделал, еслиб это помогло, но там еще оказывается больше одного конструктора нельзя? Что за бред?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто указали тип и не инициализировали массив.

```
Get: Cell[] = [];
```

Если Cell класс, то у вас ошибка.

```
this.Get[i] = new Cell(x);
```

В js наследовать массив не имеет смысла (хотя с костылями и можно).
Хорошо описано что и как здесь http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/.

Получается что массив второго уровня не получится. Потому что Get это Cell[].

```
 this.Get[i][j] //ошибка или не совсем правильно.
```

Получается вам нужно что-то похожее на:

```
export default class Cells {
  private Get: Cell[][] = [];

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {

    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      this.Get[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        this.Get[i][j] = new Cell(x, y, this._createHtmlElement());
      }
    }

  }

  _createHtmlElement(): HTMLElement {
    let t = document.createElement("div");
    t.classList.add("cell");
    return t;
  }
}
```